# How safe is to use Bootstrap JS Tab with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

AngularJS 1.4.x is used on my current project. I have to implement tabs section on page. Is it ok to use Bootstrap's JS Tab or I should move to AngularJS based solution, for example UI-Bootstrap or custom tab library?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is totally ok to use Bootstrap JS tab, but as usual angular developers are also divided into two camps, one who want to do everything in angular way(like creating directives or use UI-Bootstrap directives/components), even when it is a very small task and another who wants to mix  jquery/bootstrap library with angular and choose one or another depending on the need.
Angular-UI, will also use the same bootstrap library, but you will get an angularized wrapper over it.

My suggestion, use whatever you are comfortable with and don't bind yourself to one opinion or another.